# Implementation of footer pushes my page's middle content down

Tags: css, footer, sticky

I understand that I need to include all my content within wrapper except for my footer. The div push, I am assuming, pushes my footer to the bottom of my page. What is happening is push is pushing the rest of my content other than my header.

I am using header.php , home.php, styles.css, and footer.php 
I'm very new to website building! Any help would be very much appreciated.

**header.php**

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">  

<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
    <br><a href="index.php"><img src="img/banner.jpg" alt="Macaron" width="400"></a></br>
        <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>   
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="imagine.php">Imagine</a></li>
                        <li><a href="recipes.php">Recipes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="shops.php">Shop Locator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div> 
</div>    
<div id="middle">
```

**home.php**

```
This is the bulk of my page's content.
```

**footer.php**

```
    <div class="footer">
       <div class="container">
          <p> A macaron fan page by Avery Dao and Diana Nguyen </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**style.css**

```
     /* styles the sticky footer */
 html, body 
 {
    height: 100%;
 }

.wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -70px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer, #push 
{
    clear: both;
    height: 70px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

.footer 
{
    position:relative;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: serif;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

Comment: In your css `#footer, #push` assumes that both footer and push are using `id` but your html code show classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `#footer` to `position: absolute` and add `bottom: 0px;` it is positioned at the bottom of your page. Remember `position: absolute` sets the width to the width of the content if you don't set it so put `width: 100%` there also.

This should help it you get a horizontal scrollbar add

```
* {
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
}
```

to your CSS file